# How thread handles display in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, pthreads

I have a basic question on display in android. I am unable to understand how thread behaves when some display function is called. Specifically suppose I create a thread for displaying a thumbnail image on the the android phone screen.

1-My question is will this thread  remain active even after calling display function (i.e after the display of image starts), or will it go into some idle or sleep mode?

2-How exactly display function work

Comment: without knowing the code mechanism, no one can say, how to display method works.

Answer (score 0):

In Android apps, the main thread, or it is called ui-thread is responsible for drawing/updating UI. You can not do ui operations in worker thread.

There are though ways by which you can post ui updates from worker thread. 
If you have activity instance in worker thread or async-task, you can post activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action), which will run the Runnable on ui thread.

Comment: So you mean the main thread is ALWAYS active displaying the image?

Comment: Not sure if the ui thread is active once the activity has been paused, but I'm sure it's not activ once the activity has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update UI from any worker threads directly. You need to be on the UI thread to do that. For this, android provides us with Handler and AsyncTask which accept values from the worker threads and update the UI in the main thread. Any update to the UI can only be done from the main thread i.e. the thread created when your activity starts.

So, when you update the UI from the worker thread using handler or AsyncTask, the worker thread keeps running (if more work needs to be done) unless you destroy it. The UI thread (main thread) also runs simultaneously. So, the main thread is ready to handle any UI event (e.g. click events) that occurs on the main thread.

This  is how thread works fundamentally. You just need to know that in android, you need to give control to the main thread whenever you wish to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

[Please Read the links surely you can get it..](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)